# Ruby cannot find sqlite3 driver on windows

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am trying to set up Ruby on Rails on windows. I am using the Flash Rails distribution that looks pretty good, but there is an issue with sqlite3. I found the threads telling me to install version 1.2.3, which installed fine. I'm using ruby 1.9.0, and every time I try and run a script (e.g. rake db:create) that uses the database I get an error message "no driver for sqlite3 found".

This apparently is a missing sqlite3.dll, but I have the dll in my %PATH%, and I have also tried copying it into the directory where I am running the script from, the directory where the sqlite3 ruby code lives.

Does anyone have any ideas? If possible I want all teh ruby stuff to be self contained so I can use it from a pen drive.

EDIT: To clarify, I already used gem install to install the ruby-sqlite3 gem - it is just non functional as it cannot find the sqlite3.dll (even though it is actually present in a directory on my %PATH%)

EDIT PART 2: After doing some more digging, the problem appears that ruby will not load the sqlite3_api.dll. I have copied it all over my filesystem, I just get a failure to read file. Other dll libraries in the same directory (e.g. zlib.dll) work fine!
I tried installing the dlls into system32, and that did not work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem put simply is that sqlite3-ruby 1.2.3 is not compatible with ruby 1.9. This is caused because ruby 1.9 does not use .dll files for c libraries it uses .so files instead.  Additionally, since sqlite3_api.dll is written against msvcrt-ruby18.dll.  This means that it specifically only will support ruby 1.8.*.

The good news is that there is a fat binary version that will support both ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9.  Uninstalling all former versions of sqlite3-ruby and then installing this one.  (You may have to manually delete some versions the gem after uninstalling.) in order to install it use

```
install sqlite3-ruby --source http://gems.rubyinstaller.org
```

for more information see [this](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2009/07/06/getting-started-with-rails-and-sqlite3/) website

Comment: The source parameter is no longer required. The newer 1.2.5 version of the gem includes support for these binaries.

Comment: Paul, are you still unable to get this working? sqlite3-ruby has been out and working for many months and many users reported success. Would like to know if this is still an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the sqlite3-ruby gem:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: I did try that (that's what I was talking about with the version 1.2.3 comment). Essentially 

   gem install sqlite3-ruby 

does not work on windows, you have to do

   gem install --version 1.2.3 sqlite-ruby

which installed, but left me the problem I have described.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar happened to me recently so I thought I'd update my answer.

For reference there's a sqlite3_api.dll file located in the gem's lib directory. Also the sqlite3.dll file needs to be reachable on the path. They are different files, the first is required by the gem to interface Ruby to C code, while the second contains the actual Sqlite implementation.

It's best to get the second file from the sqlite website and extract it to the Ruby\bin directory (as you shouldn't manually put DLL's into the windows or windows\system directories any more).

So for reference "sqlite3_api.dll" needs to be in:

```
Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\sqlite3-ruby-1.2.3-x86-mswin32\lib
```

and "sqlite3.dll" needs to be on the path, possibly in:

```
Ruby\bin
```

As for the "driver not found" problem I would suggest trying the easy things first and making sure gems is installed correctly, up to date, and that the RUBYLIB and PATH environment variables are set appropriately. (System restart may be required to propagate the changes fully.)

Comment: Mine is in 

C:\Documents and Settings\greynolds\Desktop\FlashRails_Ruby1.9-Win32-0.9.0.2\Flash Rails Ruby1.9\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.0\gems\sqlite3-ruby-1.2.3-x86-mswin32\lib

Which is in my path

Comment: Well in my installation the DLL is not on the path, but just loaded as required by the gem. Also could it be that it can't find the sqlite3 gem, as the driver it refers to is the gem package, not the DLL.

Comment: I dug into the code, and the failure to load error occurs when the gem code executes "package require sqlite3_api"

Answer (score 3):

[Re this link](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/ruby-on-rails/setting-up-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-rails-development/)
Download sqlitedll-3_6_10.zip and extract into ruby/bin!

Answer (score 1):

Try going to [sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org/download.html) download page and get the zipped up dll. Then put that in your `c:\windows\system32` folder, that should allow Ruby to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your machine after running install sqlite3-ruby

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, which gem are you using? `sqlite-ruby` or `sqlite3-ruby`?

They're part of the same project, but different releases. The key is that `sqlite3` appears to have driver code included.

I assume you're attempting to use the first, since it's giving me the same error. If so, try switching.

---

Also.. How literal do you mean by this?

> but I have the dll in my %PATH%

1. **`PATH=...;C:\sqlite\sqlite3.dll`**
2. **`PATH=...;C:\sqlite`**

The first will attempt to find **`C:\sqlite\sqlite3.dll\sqlite3.dll`**, AFAIK.

Comment: I'm using sqlite3-ruby. I think something very wrong has gone wrong with the package...

Comment: I meant that the dll is in a directory (actually more than one as I have been copying it around in desperation!) that is on my path. It is in fact the sqlite3_api.dll that is not being found, according to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ruby 1.8.7 (works with 1.9.1 too)
OS is WindowsXP SP3

1. Go to
   http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
   and Download file 
   sqlitedll-3_7_0_1.zip (265.19 KiB)
   and unzip then we will get
   sqlite3.dll
2. Copy sqlite3.dll to your bin folder
       as C:\Ruby191\bin or C:\Ruby187\bin
       then it works