# Sqlite driver not found on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing the same problem as the below one. Does any one has any solutions?
[Ruby cannot find sqlite3 driver on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515639/ruby-cannot-find-sqlite3-driver-on-windows/520342)
I installed Ruby 1.9.1, then rails.Then, I installed sqlite3-ruby but thats broken.So, I deleted the directory, and installed sqlite3-ruby for win version 1.2.3.But, getting error "sqlite driver not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same problem.

sqlite3-ruby version 1.2.3 seems to be incompatible with Ruby 1.9.  Version 1.2.4 is (maybe) compatible but a windows binary version was never released, and the maintainer has announced that he's given up on building and releasing for windows.

According to [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/188627) someone is working on a fix, but it's not there yet.

So this is going to be an unhelpful answer as so far none of my researches have found a fix that's available now.  The options for getting a windows Ruby/Rails development setup today seem to be either to switch to MySQL for the development database, or move back to Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: thanks for the update.I realized that, and decided to work with Ruby 1.8.7.But, anyways I moved on to Django.

Comment: UPDATE: the latest version of the sqlite3-ruby gem now compiles and installs on Windows, and is compatible with Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the actual sqlite3 .dll for Windows.

Go to http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and download sqlitedll-3_6_13.zip and sqlite-3_6_13.zip (or whatever the most recent versions are).

Unzip both of those zipfiles. Copy sqlite3.exe to c:\windows and sqlite3.dll to c:\windows\system32

Run gem install sqlite3-ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc --version=1.2.3 --platform=mswin32 from the command line to install the SQLite3 gem (the extra flags prevent it from trying to compile some stuff that's not generally available on Windows)